# Laravel, html value '&' signs

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have database with types such as:

> Entertainment & Food,
>   Health & Care

etc.

I insert it into a dropdown like this:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('type') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<div class="type_message form-control alert-warning" style="display: none;"></div>
    <label id="type2" for="type" class="col-md-4 control-label">Type</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
    <option selected value="{{ $entity->type }}">{{ $entity->type }}</option>
    @foreach ($entities as $entity_select)
          <option value={{ $entity_select->type}}>{{ $entity_select->type }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
        @if ($errors->has('type'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('type') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I check the value of the field it looks like this:

```
<option value="Entertainment &amp; Nightlife" selected="">Entertainment &amp; Nightlife</option>
```

Therefore in the database it only adds "Entertainment" how can I avoid that?

Comment: This is not a “problem”, but how `&` _needs to_ be written in HTML, if it is not supposed to have its special meaning. It is not “therefor” that it does not store the correct value in the database; that must be due to something else.

Comment: what you mean by something else my database has a field type and it has values are as I said above, what I am doing is only retrieving that from db and outputting it in dropdown so what can possibly go wrong

Comment: As per @CBroe.  If you have a very rare circumstance which requires strictly no escaping, use `{!! .. !!}` instead of `{{ .. }}`

Comment: You just neglected to use quotes around the attribute value ... so this has nothing whatsoever to do with the ampersand, with any value that contains a space you would have had the same problem.

Comment: The accepted anser is totally wrong. `&` is a special character and it must be inserted by using `&amp;` inside html. You can use [`htmlspecialchars-decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode the html entity values before saved in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value="{!! $entity_select->type !!}">{!! $entity_select->type !!}</option>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

As mentionned in the documentation :

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your
>   application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to
>   prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

Comment: This is a valid solution to avoiding the escaping.  I want it noted though - this opens your application up to injection vulnerabilities.  Never, ever, under any circumstances, do this with data which can be manipulated or otherwise influenced by an untrusted source unless you've performed very vigorous sanitisation of your own.

Comment: For example, if somehow `$entity_select->type` becomes `<script>alert('hi');<script>` or `<iframe src="..."></iframe>`.

Comment: That is totally wrong and it will result in errors. It will append a plain`&` inside that option value, which of course is not valid and will break the code.